# Footer ends up above header, but only on homepage

Tags: html, css, wordpress, footer

I'm trying desperately to get the footer to act properly on the homepage of this website I'm working on. On all pages except the homepage it fits nicely at the bottom of the page.

However on the homepage it jumps to the top of the screen and I don't have a clue why. I've been scouring the HTML and CSS and can't find the glitch.

Site: http://dumbbell-divas.com/

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you have `#maincontent{ position: absolute; }` make it `position: relative`

Comment: Thanks so much! I'd vote you guys up but I don't have enough reputation yet :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove **position:absolute** from **div#maincontent**